# Can I save my lucky bamboo by replanting its leaves?

Tags: houseplants, diseases, transplanting, cuttings, lucky-bamboo

My lucky bamboo is turning yellow from the middle outwards, most likely because of microbes which entered through a wound. I have already cut off a small green top of the bamboo, disinfected the wound I created by cutting it, waxed the wound and replanted the bamboo, but now this top is also turning yellow from bottom up. Is there any way to save my lucky bamboo? Will its green leaves be able to grow roots if I cut them off and replant them?[image]